# uninitialized constant UsersController on logout on devices gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to logout form device gem and it show me error like this. Page will crash with this url  http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out

```
uninitialized constant UsersController

Rails.root: /var/www/rails/hustlo_dev/trunk
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
```

Comment: could you post your routes. run `rake routes` in your console

Comment: It's a `devise` instead of `device`